# Is it possible in Magento to remove the checkout steps completely?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a design for a checkout page on magento and everything is displayed all at once without the steps, is it possible to have the checkout page as just one big checkout without the ajax loading in new content after step progression.

[image]

Comment: It's possible but not natively, search for **Magento one step checkout extension** on Google.

Comment: It is certainly possible however could you be a bit more specific, is there a certain step you wish to remove or all steps completely to create a 1 step checkout?

Comment: Remove all the steps all together, we have tried to have a go at it but it seems a huge effort we have had to rewrite some of the core and extend a few classes i have updated the question with basically a design of what we have.